# Как сделать сумму двух столбцов в SQL и вывести новый столбец с результатами этих сумм

Tags: mysql

В этой таблице мне необходимо добавить новый столбик с результатами суммы двух столбцов Math и Rus для каждой строчки. Как это сделать?
[image: Students]

Comment: Обычно все пишут сумму всего столбца. а мне надо для каждой строчки по отдельности

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, (Math + Rus) as summ FROM tabl;
```

Если вы имеете ввиду столбик, который сам будет рассчитываться, вот пример использования виртуального столбца(был ответ где-то, но я его потерял):

```
create table t (
    num1 int,
    num2 int,
    sum int as (num1 + num2)) ;

insert into t
(num1, num2)
values
    (1, 2);

select * from t;
```

Выведет 1(num1), 2(num2), 3(sum)